# Where is the iPhone 5SE simulator in Xcode? Or is 5SE the same as 5S?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I got a crash report which occurred on iPhone 5SE. As the build has been thoroughly tested on iPhone 5S (actual device), I decided to test the build on iPhone 5SE simulator on Xcode. Unfortunately 5SE simulator is nowhere to be found.

This is the listing on Devices window:
[image: Devices listing screenshot]

And this is what options I have if I try to create a new simulator:
[image: Create a new simulator screenshot]

I know the 5SE is basically a hardware refresh of 5S and screen dimensions &al. are the same. But, **is it the *same* device *simulator-wise?*** Or am I missing a simulator (and how to get one)?

My Xcode version is 7.3.1 and I see no available updates on App Store. I also checked the updates on Xcode's Preferences → Components window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 7.3 does not include an iPhone SE Simulator Device Type.  You should be able to test whatever you need using the iPhone 5s.  Xcode 8 includes an iPhone SE Simulator Device Type.

Comment: Yep, iPhone S**E** simulator is indeed included in Xcode 8.

Answer (score 0):

As I knew, iPhone 5SE has a same size with iPhone 5s, but the hardware is same with iPhone 6s.  So, I think you should use iPhone 6s for your work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find iPhone SE simulator in Xcode 7.3. However, you can find it in Xcode beta 8. If ever you want to test iPhone SE, you can test it on iPhone 5S since it is of same screen size.